# Can I skip the master's of an American PhD.?

Tags: phd, masters, united-states

I am interested in studying abroad in America. I am currently doing a M.Sc. in Quantum Science and Technology in Germany and would like to start a Ph.D. in the same subject at one of the big American universities (MIT, Harvard, Caltech ...) after I've finished my degree. I noticed that every one of these programs has another master's integrated, for which I should already have completed the coursework. Can I skip that part's courses? If only a portion, how large of a portion could I skip?

Is there anyone who knows about this stuff (especially for the universities mentioned above) or who might've already gone through what I described above?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can skip the *courses*?

Comment: Yes sorry if that wasnt clear

Comment: Entirely up to the specific institution/department whether they'd let you skip any courses.

Comment: I’m surprised we have not had this question before but I am not turning it up …

Comment: I'd also remark, channeling Buffy, that for your own personal sake you really can't rely on getting in to any of whatever Hollywood-inspired list of "top US schools" you're imagining is, just as a numerical matter. Worrying about grindy course requirements rather than applying enough places to get a position is putting the cart before the horse in that regard.

Comment: @AnonymousM I know, but to stay in academia you have to have visited one of the very prominent research groups - and these, as one could imagine, are usually found at these schools. So this parameter would be my parameter I will base my final decision on rather than list of "top US schools".

Comment: "I know, but to stay in academia you have to have visited one of the very prominent research groups" You say that as if it were an established fact.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase it: I have observed that in order to substantially increase your chances to stay in academia, you have to have done your Ph.D. at one of the widely known research groups of a specific sub field. Some professors, like Immanuel Bloch from my university, also like to boast about this fact (see his cv [link](https://www.quantum-munich.de/106277/immanuelblochcv.pdf). Other examples include this research group from Yale, where actually 3 of my professors I came in contact with went [link](https://www.eng.yale.edu/tanglab/alumni.htm). But I would also like to be proven wrong.

Comment: I'm not really sure how either of those links provides evidence for your assertion. Yes, doing your Ph.D. at a place which is prestigious in your subfield certainly helps. No, you have not shown that you need to do your Ph.D. at MIT, Harvard, Caltech, ... or else your chances of working in that field are shot to hell.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil "No, you have not shown that you need to do your Ph.D. at MIT, Harvard, Caltech, ... or else your chances of working in that field are shot to hell." This is not what I've claimed. However, this discussion is pretty subjective, so maybe we agree on a tie? :P

Answer (score 4):

This question's in a bit of a gray area in that the main answer is, as a comment points out: Whether you can skip any courses, requirements, or recommendations tends to vary on a program-by-program basis. You'll need to contact Departments individually if this is a serious consideration.

To add a quick anecdote that may display the scope of variance, I can report different allowances within a **single** PhD program. The punchline in this particular circumstance is that the requirements were written flexibly. That probably does not generalize, however.

1. I was an undergraduate student at the same place as my PhD, but did a 1 year Masters in Europe in between. The Dept allowed me to skip the graduate courses I took with them during my undergraduate and nothing else. I sat "first year" and PhD qualifying examinations in the same semester, and eventually graduated in 4 academic years (accounting for the 1 year MSc). That last part basically required my PhD adviser to approve.
2. Some friends were undergraduate students in the same Dept. and then continued directly to a PhD in the same Dept. They too were not required to re-sit graduate classes they had taken as undergraduates, and I learned later were also allowed to skip some "first year" examinations as well. No other requirements waived, they eventually graduated in 5 academic years.
3. Some PhD students started directly from undergraduate programs at different US institutions. They had taken comparable graduate level courses as undergraduates, but were required to take those again at the PhD institution.

These are just 3 of several variants I encountered within one Dept. It's not going to be useful to you to conceptualize of US PhD programs as consisting of 1 European Masters + 1 European PhD. Each US PhD program has its own requirements which often includes some coursework that a European MS might cover.

Comment: I wanted to leave as a comment: I wouldn't blame anyone for flagging this Q overall as too dependent on personal factors, though I think it's a question which does depend on such factors but that is not obvious from the *form* of the question.

Comment: Thank you for giving me some anecdotal references and giving me some context of how this could go about.

Comment: The commonality of those students who were allowed to skip classes - they had taken those classes at THAT university. In my experience, the only time this works if if a student has taken the same course at THAT university or some other university ranked substantially higher. In my US program, I don't know of any students with a foreign masters who were allowed to skip classes. I do know of one student who was able to transfer in a single class from a previous partial PhD at MIT (our school was ranked a dozen or so places below MIT)

Comment: @Dawn I agree, this was also my impression. But my vantage point is pretty limited, so I'm hesitant to put any speculative generalization into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most US doctoral students start with only a bachelors. Few require a masters at any point, though many make one available along the way, sometimes just by filing paperwork and sometimes by writing a masters thesis (my case).

Actual requirements vary. In my doctoral program (math, but long ago), there were only two requirements: pass comprehensives and write a dissertation acceptable to the faculty.

But all students took courses as they were more advanced than undergraduate courses and were designed to enable passing comps, as well as giving a broad math background. Quite a number of the courses I took in the doctoral program had the same names as undergraduate courses but the level of instruction and difficulty was quite a bit higher. One way to think of it is that undergrad courses give the basics, but if you want real math insight you may need to go beyond what you can get in undergrad education.

Contrary to a comment, there was no "cohort" of students that needed to progress together. That may be different in other fields than math, I suppose. But you needed to pass those courses that you did take.

A doctoral student will probably have an advisor, not necessarily their research advisor, to help them choose whatever necessary courses are needed. So you get some guidance and aren't entirely on your own. The research advisor can be chosen later and isn't normally needed for admissions. If a student is already skilled enough in the required (comp exam) topics they might need to choose a research advisor relatively soon.

And, as mentioned in a comment, I always recommend students to "cast a wide net" of doctoral institutions. You don't just "enroll" at a place like MIT (or anywhere). You "apply" and are accepted or (most often) not. Top level institutions are very (very) competitive in admissions, accepting some fraction which tends to be smaller at the top since there are a lot of applicants and a limited number of slots. You need good letters of recommendation for admissions.

You won't need to repeat a masters, certainly. You might need some courses. But you probably won't need to take any courses in things you've already *mastered*, though mastering has a high bar. The masters program you are in might prepare you to take comps in some US institution or not. Probably there will be overlap. Possibly (probably?) there will be some gaps.

There are really two gates. The first is admissions. Your background and potential will be weighed and measured. The second gate is comprehensives, sometimes including orals, and folks may (will?) be looking for insight, not just competence. Now you can do the dissertation, which I'm not terming a gate, though there is a high bar there, also.

Answer (score -2):

You would transfer classes you already took in Germany into the program at the US. Rules for transferring are specific to the university and will depend on the class you took and the class you want to transfer. There are also rules about the amount of classes (credit units) you are allowed to transfer into a program.

For a Ph.D., you usually do not lack credit hours to graduate, so the latter might or might not be a problem.

However, there is (in general) no way to just skip ahead to the thesis part that you know from Germany. You might have to pass a comprehensive examination and defend your thesis approval.

Comment: Rules on undergraduate course transfer and PhD course transfer are going to be different. In general, most US PhD programs at that level will require the student to retake the courses with their cohort, in my experience.

Comment: @Dawn, in math, I would think that a "cohort" would be very unusual. There are too many different math areas. It may well be the case in some other fields, I guess.

Comment: @Buffy Let me rephrase - it is not about the "cohort" as such, but rather that they don't trust the graduate classes at any institute not ranked LOTS higher than theirs.